# How can I adjust this using the new NavigationStack or even just adjusting the NavigationLink using value/label instead? Need to fix double 'back'

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, back-button, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to 'remove' the previous views after navigating more than 2 tabs away from the 'ContentView'. Currently, I am running into double 'back' options. One will take me back 1 view and the other will take me back to my 'ContentView'. I am brand new to swiftUI and coding in general so any help is greatly appreciated and I am sorry if this is a super simple question that feels way overcomplicated in my head.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedView: Int? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 50) {
                Spacer()
                
                NavigationLink(destination: CustomizePlayerView(), tag: 0, selection: $selectedView) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedView = 0
                    }) {
                        Text("Start New Career")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                            .background(Color.orange)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                    }
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: LoadGameView(), tag: 1, selection: $selectedView) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedView = 1
                    }) {
                        Text("Load Saved Career")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                            .background(Color.orange)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                    }
                }

                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 400)
            .background(Image("Image")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 900, height: 400))
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I am trying to have a single 'Back' option each time I navigate to the next view, but I ended up stacking these and also used destination/tag for my NavigationLink which I see is deprecated so I am trying to understand the alternative options Value/Label and how they can be applied.

Comment: You haven’t showed enough code but if your back buttons are stacking it likely means that you have more than 1 NavigationView, most apps only need one at the very top, remove the rest.

Comment: That fixed it! I had a different view controller that I also used NavigationView on not thinking about how the navigationlink could still work without putting the NavView in both places. Thank you!